# Is there anyway to change coverage in wireless node?

Tags: tcl, ns2

I'm using NS2 tool for simulating some VANET scenario between wireless nodes.

How can I change the coverage distance of a specific wireless node, I've checked so far:

- NS2 manual
- Some digging on the Internet

But I didn't find a solution, maybe it's some parameters related to antenna type or so?

Here's my node configuration:

```
ns node-config -adhocRouting $val(adhocRouting) \
    -llType $val(ll) \
    -macType $val(mac) \
    -ifqType $val(ifq) \
    -ifqLen $val(ifqlen) \
    -antType $val(ant) \
    -propType $val(prop) \
    -phyType $val(netif) \
    -channelType $val(chan) \
    -topoInstance $topo \
    -macTrace OFF \
    -agentTrace ON \
    -routerTrace ON \
    -movementTrace ON \
    -wiredRouting OFF
```

Where:

```
set val(chan)           Channel/WirelessChannel ;
set val(prop)           Propagation/TwoRayGround;
set val(netif)          Phy/WirelessPhy         ;
set val(mac)            Mac/802_11              ;
set val(ifq)            Queue/DropTail/PriQueue ;
set val(ll)             LL                      ;
set val(ant)            Antenna/OmniAntenna     ;
set val(ifqlen)         50                      ;
set val(adhocRouting)   AODV                    ;
set val(cbr-rate)       100kbps                 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transmission range of the node is given by TwoRayGround formula in threshold.cc

```
              Pr * d^4 * L
      Pt = ---------------------------
             Gt * Gr * (ht^2 * hr^2)
```

If a distance is given, Pt can be calculated by above formula.

e.g.

```
  Tx Range           Pt_
   100m             0.00721383
   150m             0.03652
   200m             0.115421
   250m             0.28179
   300m             0.58432
```

Comment: Can you provide a description of each parameter of this formula

Comment: Pt : Antenna power. 

    Pr :  the received power and it is replaced with RxThresh_  whose  value is 3.652 e-10 .
 
    Gt and Gr is the is the transmitter antenna gain and receiver antenna gain respectively.

    ht and hr is the transmit antenna height and receive antenna height.

    l: System loss

Comment: Thanks. that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer, and as expected, it's a parameter relative to physical antenna.

So, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611571/what-is-the-value-of-pt-for-range-of-20m-in-ns2/29638541#29638541) answer, here is some coverage values:

```
Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 8.5872e-4    ;# 40m

Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 1.33826e-3   ;# 50m

Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 7.214e-3     ;# 100m

Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.2818       ;# 250m

Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 2.28289e-11  ;# 500m
```