# What is the Pt_ and freq_ values for 2050m and 1000m in NS2?

Tags: ns2

```
Phy/WirelessPhy set CPThresh_ 10.0;
Phy/WirelessPhy set CSThresh_ 3.23e-13;#2050m
Phy/WirelessPhy set RXThresh_ 5.71e-12;#1000m
Phy/WirelessPhy set bandwidth_ 512kb;
Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 1.1272;
Phy/WirelessPhy set freq_ 2.4e+9;
Phy/WirelessPhy set L_ 1.0;
Antenna/OmniAntenna set X_ 0;
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Y_ 0;
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Z_ 1.5;
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gt_ 1;
Antenna/OmniAntenna set Gr_ 1;
```

I used threshold.cc file to calculate values. Simulation is successful when node distance is lower than 550m.What should I change to simulate for 1000m and 2050m?

Also,

```
highestAntennaZ_ = 1.5,  distCST_ = 250.0
```

This file contained 1000m and 250m of transmission ranges of nodes. But it selecting smallest one. Why?

Comment: 2.05e+3 = 2.05 x 103 = 2,050 https://iconvert.org/calculate/notation/2.05e+3 ... 1e+3 = 1 x 103 = 1,000 https://iconvert.org/calculate/notation/1e+3 ... Ref.1: https://iconvert.org/calculate/notation/6.93e+2 ... 2: https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/scientific-notation-converter.html Etc. etc. ... Google, Convert Decimal to Scientific Notation :
https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/scientific-notation-converter.php

Comment: Hi Larsen,Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hi Larsen,Thanks for reply. I researched your comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611571/what-is-the-value-of-pt-for-range-of-20m-in-ns2 ,and some other your replies. I will describe my question in details. I need to simulate in NS2 a network of wireless nodes with different transmission range. I changed Phy/WireleesPhy values as above. When I simulating,It only successful if the distance between nodes is lower than 550 m. But I need to simulate for 1000m. For above codings, it selects lowest radio transmission.

Comment: ns2 is old, can't do everything. Unsupported for years. All 3000 examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tptvzNOYJWeoA28Vm92sFIl0w1_qMAvi/view?usp=sharing ... **Tree** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing ... **ns2 doc** https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/index.html